# ImportError: cannot import name 'MeanSquaredLogarithmicError'

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, importerror

I am new to tensorflow and I just created a new anaconda environment and installed tensorflow with follow commands on anaconda promt:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
activate py35
conda install spyder
conda install tensorflow
```

Then I opened spyder from the enviroment and tensorflow is imported just fine , but when I try to import `from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredLogarithmicError` I am getting an error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MeanSquaredLogarithmicError'
```

Any idea of why ??

Comment: `conda install keras`?

Comment: does `import tensorflow as tf` work?

Comment: Yes `import tensorflow as tf` works , why is there a need to install keras ? `from tensorflow.keras import Model, Sequential` this works

Comment: I just installed keras, but nothing changed same problem

Comment: What about to not importing but just using in code like: `msle = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError()`? Does it also throw error?

Comment: It throws this `*** AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.losses' has no attribute 'MeanSquaredLogarithmicError'`

Comment: Followed your exact steps in conda prompt and yes the issue is replicating , then I checked in `python 3.7 and conda version (4.1.0) where i have installed tensorflow using "pip install tensorflow==2.5.0" `  , no issue is happening .